# XML Parsing.....is AML is supported in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I'm comfortable with XML Parsing, but my response is coming in AML Aras markup language. Could any one let me know. is AML is supported by iPhone? If YES how can I Parse AML response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If AML is XML(what seems to be true `<Item type="ECN" action="get"></Item>`), you can parse it like XML... There is [plenty of documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone+xml) out there about how to do that on an iPhone