# How to parsing Aras Markup language into iphone application SDK?

Tags: iphone

I want details of parsing a Aras Markup language into iphone application SDK ?

Comment: duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430667/xml-parsing-is-aml-is-supported-in-iphone/3430962#3430962

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Aras Markup is simply XML so you should be fine with any XML parser such as NSXMLParser